# How to use the Currency Filter in Ionic 3 or Angular? (US $ 1.000.000,00)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How Can I change "." By "," in ionic 3 or Angular currency format.

I need to place the prices in this format or mask (US $ 1.000.000,00), in ionic 3.

```
{{price | currency: "US"}}
```

// result (`$ 1,000,000.00`) // when I would be in need (US $ 1.000.000,00)

More examples:

```
US 1

US 100.00

US 1.000.000,00

US 1.000.000.000,00
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just leverage standard pipe:

```
 <div>{{ 1000000 | currency: 'US $ ' }}</div>
```

what goes after "currency:" in quotes will define the symbol etc added in front of your number.

Source: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Comment: Thanks but here the result would be ($ 1,000,000.00) // when I would need is (US $ 1.000.000,00)

Comment: hmm for me it shows exactly as you asked for it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7sts8w - can you check this link?

Comment: I understand, but what I really need is to replace the commas where points go and the points where commas go like this (US $ 1.000.000,00)

Comment: ahh sorry now I get it:) let me fix that;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your locale for a region that uses that mask, for example "pt-BR":

```
{{price | currency:'US':'symbol':'1.2-2':'pt-BR'}}
```

The result:

> US $ 1.000.000,00

Another option is to use a library that you can setup this configurations. Take a look at [ng2-currency-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask).